# Integration testing load time of a data call

Tags: c#, testing, integration-testing

I currently have a method call that is taking a long time to load and sometimes timing out. I want to write an integration test to make sure my data is returned in a reasonable amount of time, before I attempt to make the data call faster. How would I do this?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetResults_ReturnsDataInReasonableAmountOfTime_Test()
    {
        var result = _dataAccess.GetListOfResults();
        Assert.IsTrue(##How do I Test that result was returned in under 2 seconds?##);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example with an `AutoResetEvent`

```
    private AutoResetEvent _resetEvent;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetResults_ReturnsDataInReasonableAmountOfTime_Test()
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            // your long method call
            _resetEvent.Set();
        }).Start();

        Assert.IsTrue(_resetEvent.WaitOne(2000));
    }
```